# Run database query as Scheduled task on system startup

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have to schedule a task which do database operations on MS-SQL server 2008 on system start up.

I have made a schduled task which runs a batch file containing php file which does the db operations. But the issue is when i log in the remote server i find that the scheduled task is successfully completed without the expected database operations. When I run the same batch file manually it runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add logging to you PHP file to see if it is called and what it does when/if it is called...  You should see the issue.

Also without code it is difficult to advise you what the issue is!